# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in drupal_http_request().... common.in

Tags: 7

I have installed Drupal and I am getting the following Notice messages:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in drupal_http_request() (line 989 of /home/sites/nucreativetesting.co.uk/public_html/my-site/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in drupal_http_request() (line 993 of /home/sites/nucreativetesting.co.uk/public_html/my-site/includes/common.inc).
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in drupal_http_request() (line 993 of /home/sites/nucreativetesting.co.uk/public_html/my-site/includes/common.inc).
```

This is the second time that I have run into these messages. This time i have installed from a purchased Drupal theme, and the first time I used a vanilla install of Drupal core. They seem harmless as the old site worked fine. I would love to know what they are about and if I can get rid of them.

Please let me know if there is anything I can do to provide more helpful information.

Comment: It can happen when the size of a URL in a GET request is too large (e.g. [this issue with Spambot](https://drupal.org/node/1983654)). It's pretty common but I've never seen it with just Drupal core installed